# How to clear text field value of an external page in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have two pages index.html and external.html.In index.html i have two text field. Inserting some text in those text field and clicking on a button i goes to external.html page.This external.html page has one button linking to index.html. When in click in that button it moves me to index.html.

Now the problem is when i move from external.html to index.html,  the  text fields remainds its previous value. i wanted it to clear its previous value when coming to index.html page. How to do that, please help me.

index.html

```
<section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">      
        <h1>First</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content" >

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $( function(){
            $( '#name_field' ).val( "" );

        });


        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.clearme').focus(function() {
            $(this).val("");
          });
        });

    </script>


    <label for="name" >Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_field" value="" class="clearme" placeholder="Enter Name"/>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email_field" value="" placeholder="Enter Email Id" />

    <input type="submit" id="button" value="External Page" data-theme="b"  onclick="_gotopage( 'http://localhost/test/external.html' );"/>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-theme="d" >    

    </footer>   
</section>
```

external.html

```
<section id="secondpage" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">      
        <h1>External</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content" >

    <script type="text/javascript" >


    </script>
           <input type="submit" id="comment_enter_button" value="Index Page" data-theme="b"  onclick="_gotopage( 'http://localhost/test/index.html' );"/>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-theme="d" >    

    </footer>   
</section>
```

script.js

```
function gotopage( gotopage )
{ 
  $.mobile.changePage($( gotopage ), { transition: "slide"});
}



function _gotopage( page )
{
  $.mobile.changePage( page);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function () {
    $('.clearme').val("");
});
```

Comment: This is what i am expecting. Thank you.